# How to select Razor Pages from one of many Razor Class Library dlls?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, razorengine, razor-pages

**Requirement 1:**

I have a few `Razor Class Libraries` namely `MyFeature1.dll`, `MyFeature2.dll`, `MyFeature3.dll` which all have the same file structure and files but the content vary by images, colors, fonts only.

NB. I purposefully don't want to create one `MyFeatures.dll` with different `Areas\Features\Pages` folder.

**Requirement 2:**

The `PageModel` is the same for all those variations. Only the `cshtml` content are different, and thus three dlls.

**Requirement 3:**

`/california/feature1/` route should load `MyFeature1.dll` and use the Pages from it.
`/california/feature2/` route should load `MyFeature2.dll` and use the Pages from it.
`/california/feature3/` route should load `MyFeature3.dll` and use the Pages from it.

I'm currently planning to use three RCL (Razor Class Library), one RCL for the `PageModel`. What I don't know is that what class I have to override to tell Razor to load the correct dll based on the router.